# Strange outputs of mixed up std::cout

Tags: c++, std, cout

C++'s std::cout seems to be an interesting thing. I tried the following program on my C++ compiler today:

```
cout<<"!"<<"@"<<endl;
cout<<"!"<<cout<<"@"<<endl;
cout<<"!"<<(cout<<"@")<<endl;
```

And the outputs are rather curious:

```
!@
!0x601068@
@!0x601068
```

The first line is pedestrian; the second is understandable; however, the third line is beyond my knowledge. Could someone explain the output? Thank you guys all in advance!

Ziyao Wei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
cout<<"!"<<(cout<<"@")<<endl;
```

It is first executing:

```
(cout << "@")
```

Note: It could have executed something else first, but the compiler optimized this sub-expression and found it could move this to the start of the statement without breaking any constraints.

The result of this expression is a stream (cout). So the resulting expression is:

```
cout<<"!"<< cout <<endl;
```

This results in:

```
@!<pointer>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is an optimisation which causes the sub-expression to occur first?  I thought it was sequence points which did this.

Comment: There is a sequence point at the beginning and end of the statement. A sequence point before and after each call to a method (Note: operator << is a method call). Everything else can be moved around. The only restriction here is that `(cout<<"@")` must be fully evaluated before it is used as a parameter. Weather this is done before or after the first method call is dependent on what optimizations the compiler is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthes affect the order of evaluation here as in any other expression (<< is an operator).  Because the expression has [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), those side-effects occur in the same order as the expression evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

This third line illustrates the syntactic sugar that is the insertion operator.

Essentially the `(cout<<"@")` expression is evaluated first, resulting in the `@`, which returns the stream `cout` itself.

Its only then that the `!` first, followed by the expression is sent to `cout`.

Its equivalent to:

```
operator<<( operator<<( operator<<(cout,"!"), ( operator<<(cout,"@") ) ), endl);
                                                ^------------------^
```

The highlighted section is an expression which has to be evaluated before any functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

My supposition -- the parentheses in the 3rd line make the `cout<<"@"` execute first, which puts the `@` at the start of the line.  Then the `cout.operator<<("!")` executes which puts the `!` in place.  And then the `ostream` that `cout.operator<<("!")` returns runs its `operator<<()` which is given the `ostream` that `cout<<"@"` returned, thus outputting the `0x601068`.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the second line, why does the third confuse you?

First of all, the expression in the parentheses is evaluated (but the order of evaluation is unspecified), thus `@` is wrote on the standard output; such expression returns a reference to `cout`, as happens always with insertion operators, since otherwise they couldn't be chained.

Now that this part of the expression is evaluated, everything proceeds as normal: what is on the line is wrote from left to right: first the `!`, then the value returned from the expression in the parentheses (i.e. the reference to `cout` and then the `endl`.